# vlookup with index formula to retrieve values

Tags: excel

I am look for an approximate match between `display name` and `itgname` to retrieve the `itglueid` value to the right of the `itgname` column.

I was able to use vlookup like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"*",H:H,1,FALSE)
```

but I want to return the value that is in column J but use column H as the reference point. (If that makes any sense?)

I also tried to use index match but that wasn't giving me a good approximate match from column H like `vlookup` does.

Here is a picture of what I am looking for:
[image]

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using VLOOKUP, you can just extend the match range and change the result column reference like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2&"*",H:J,3,FALSE)
```

If you have Excel 365, you can use XLOOKUP instead and it supports this wildcard lookup and can more explicitly deliver your results without a risk that if anyone ever puts another column between H and J, it will still work.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2&"*",H:H,J:J,,2)
```